# How to dynamically disable html <select> in JSTL?

Tags: html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I try to use

```
<select id="_${sec_field}_id" name="${sec_field}" multiple="${multiple}" "${(empty disabled) ? 'disabled' : ' '}" >
```

To get the `<select>` options dynamically enabled/disabled

But Eclipse give me the alerts:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Element type "select" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
- Attribute """ has no value
```

So is there any solution that we can work out the disable of html `<select>` in JSTL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove those doublequotes around the EL expression which prints the `disabled` attribute name. Doublequotes should be placed around the attribute **value** only (the part after `=`).

```
<select ... ${empty disabled ? 'disabled' : ''}>
```

otherwise you end up with

```
<select ... "">
```

or

```
<select ... "disabled">
```

which are syntactically wrong.